# Crashlytics issues not showing on dashboard

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am currently on  [Crashlytics] Version 3.7.0 (102).

Last week I could still check any issue that had been recorded on Fabric dashboard.

I just logged in to Fabric account today and every opened and closed issue were gone.

[image]

In the setting page the sums of issues and crashes of my apps are still there, but I can't check details of any issue from dashboard anymore.

[image]
[image]

Answer is working fine, the recording and sending mechanism may not be the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: I've noticed weird stuff with Crashlytics the past week, too. Data reported the following day doesn't match data I observed, mismatches between installs on iTunesConnect & fabric.io, etc.

Comment: Mike from Fabric and Crashlytics here. If you share your bundle id or package name, I can look into this more. Also, one thing to note is that the default time filter is now 7 days. If you switch to all-time, do you see what you'd expect?

Comment: @MikeBonnell thanks for reply. Old crashes are showing now when I switch time filter to all-time, but there has been nothing recorded during the last ten days. I'm pretty sure there were issues caused during that period.

Comment: Thanks @bluenowhere can you share the bundle id or package name? If not publicly, then feel free to email into support(at)fabric(dot)io.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I sent the bundle id to support team already, thanks for helping!